# Netstat shows numerous CLOSE_WAIT states for mysql connections

Tags: java, mysql

The output of netstat -an shows many mysql connections in CLOSE_WAIT state and when i checked the processlist in mysql using 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' the connections shown in netstat do not appear. What possible could be the reason for this. I use tomcat with mysql-connector and use a Connection Pool as well.

Is it that the application is not closing the mysql connection or is there any other reason for this behaviour... sometimes the CLOSE_WAIT reaches over 200.

On the application level i made sure that i close all the connections(make sure i issue a close() command in the finally block) created using jdbc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are these on the server or the application machine?

Comment: *"Is it that the application is not closing the mysql connection"* It would seem so: http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2006-January/007068.html Sounds like an issue with the connection pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the netstat is done on the application machine, it could mean misconfigured MySQL servers.

Please check following global variables in MySQL server,

```
  interactive_timeout
  wait_timeout
```

If any of these are too short, it will cause this problem. We normally set both to 1 hour when pooling is used.

The TCP is stuck in CLOSE_WAIT state when server closes connection but the connection pool hasn't got a chance to close the connection.

Comment: Interactive timeout value is 28800 and wait_timeout value is 1200.. i guess they are not short, any other reason why this happens??

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue with IIS. 
On windows machine we had:

`$ netstat -on | sed '1,4d' | sed 's/:/ /g' | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c`

`287 CLOSE_WAIT`

`121 ESTABLISHED`

`2 SYN_SENT`

`1 TIME_WAIT`

On MySQL:

`mysql> show global variables like "interactive_timeout";

interactive_timeout 28800

mysql> show global variables like "wait_timeout";

wait_timeout 1440
`

We change it wait_timeout=3660, will see it it will help.

PS: wait_timeout=1440 was done because db previosly had up to 400 of sleep connections...